# Fix floating box in Html

Tags: html, css

So I want my boxes to stay the same position even when I shrink my window.
But for now when I shrink them, they will resize and push the floating box to the bottom space and not making a line together.

```css
.bodybox1
{           
   border:1px solid black;
   width:45%;            
   background:white;
   margin:1% auto 2% auto;            
   text-align:center;
   font-size:2em;
   padding:3%;
   overflow:hidden;
} 

.boxcoverblack
{
  text-align:center;
  width:120px;
  padding:7%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:2%;                                                
}

.signuparea
{
  width:30%;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  padding:3%;
  overflow:hidden
} 

.signuptext
{
   text-align:center;
   width:180px;
   padding:7%;
   word-spacing:15px;
   border:1px black solid;           
   line-height:35px;
}      

.freeshipping
{              
  float:left; /*image*/
}
```

```html
<div class="bodybox1">
  <img class="freeshipping" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" width="500" height="300" >
  <div class="signuparea">

    <div class="signuptext">Sign up to get freeshipping coupon code! ( per phone number ) 
    </div> 
    <div class="boxcoverblack">Sign up</div>

  </div>  
</div>
```

help me please....

http://jsfiddle.net/abxf6c9h/

Comment: So I guess you want the green and yellow items to stay the same height all the time or to stay inline when  you resize ?

Comment: Sorry, I have used the wrong link, this is the new one I'm currently working on..

Comment: Arghh...This link should work!!

Comment: Yes this new link is now working..Please help me with this one.

Comment: your code changed a lot now . Which boxes ? What do you want to stay inline ? Please correct the question .

Comment: The only boxes that is not floating in line are only one. It is very obvious isn't it
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bodybox1 {

  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  margin: 1% auto 2% auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try this. I guess you want this box displayed as flexed. Tell me if that gave you a hint . I just added:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

See my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/abxf6c9h/1/

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a bit of arrangements :
use

```
display:inline-block
```

instead of

```
float:left
```

use vertical-align:top to remove the auto centering align from the wraping div
and finaly

```
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:nowrap;
```

to the parent of the 2 involved divs

Here's the result
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9qbr1pv/)

Comment: Ohh no...You got the earlier link from me..that is the other link which is from other people..

Comment: I have now updated the latest link...Can you help me to take a look?? Sorry.